# Toggle Button in Material Components for Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, togglebutton, material-components-android

The material design guidelines suggests the use of Toggle Buttons as per this link:

https://material.io/design/components/buttons.html#toggle-button

Where do I find this component for Android. All I can find is MaterialButton. Does it have toggle behavior? Or is there another component that I am missing?

https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

Comment: Imagine a heart icon, you click it, the heart becoms filled, you click it again, the heart becomes empty. A CheckBox is a toggle button. So is RadioButton Anything that has an off and on state is a toggle button.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what you were looking but, it's a library: https://savvyapps.com/blog/toggle-button-solution-android-app

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`MaterialButtonToggleGroup`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md#toggle-button) component.

```
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                />

           <!-- ....  -->

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

[image]